# clearcase and sonar qube integration for source code quality

Tags: sonarqube, clearcase, sonarqube-scan

I am looking for a confirmation regarding a code quality control tool (sonarqube) which can be integrated/used along with my version control tool clearcase.

I heard about sonarQube but not sure whether we can use it along with Clearcase. I would like to know if it is possible to use sonarqube along with Clearcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [described here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/integrate-sonarqube-devops-environment/index.html), SonarQube would integrate itself more with the successor of ClearCase: [IBM RTC](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/rtc) and its Jazz Source Control module.

[image: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/integrate-sonarqube-devops-environment/figure002.png]

That being said, the [SonarQube Plugin Library](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library) page does mention a [ClearCase plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase), for you to try.

Answer (score 2):

Despite VonC's excellent answer, it's not clear to me what you mean by "integrate with" so I want to expand a little on the topic.

SonarQube does not:

- check out your code
- build your code

These things must be handled externally to your analysis, typically by a CI engine such as Jenkins (or the Jazz Build Engine).

The SonarAnalyzer does:

- execute static analysis of your code
- contact your SCM to get "blame" information for each line of each file.

The blame data retrieved by the analyzer is used to associate each source file line with the last committer in the SonarQube UI, and to assign to issues to their assumed authors.

Comment: That is worth mentioning, in addition to my answer. +1